# STM32 UART2 BRR Not Giving Expected Results

Tags: c, stm32, uart, cpu-registers

I am currently working with an STM32F407VG on the Discovery board. I am going through the peripherals and trying to get each one working by manipulating the registers only (no HAL).

When I go to initialize UART2 it is transmitting the character I write to the DR but it is doing so ~12x faster than expected, I'm shooting for 9600 baud. I measured this using an oscilloscope (~8-9 us per bit) and playing with the baud rate in Putty (111,111 baud to show the actual character).

I am maxing out the clock speed of the chip 168 MHz SYSCLK, APB1 Prescaler "/4", APB2 Prescaler "/2". I am pretty sure my clocks are at what they are supposed to be, to verify I set up TIMER12, which shares the APB1 clock and set the prescaler to 8400 and had an interrupt generated every time there was a compare match (CCR = 5000) and overflow. I measured this with the oscilloscope and I am getting a 1 Hz square wave as expected which means that the APB1 for Timer 12 is at 84 MHz.

Here is my clock init code:

```
void SysClockConfig ( void ){

    //setting up the MCO output to see the clock signal
    //RCC->CFGR |= ( 6 << 24 ) | (3 << 21 ) | ( 4 << 27 );

    //1. ENABLE HSE and wait for the HSE to become Ready
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON;
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY));

    // 2. Set the POWER ENABLE CLOCK and VOLTAGE REGULATOR
    RCC->APB1ENR  |= RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;
    PWR->CR |= PWR_CR_VOS;

    // 3. Configure the FLASH PREFETCH and the LATENCY Related Settings
    FLASH->ACR = FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_5WS;

    //4. Configure the PRESCALARS HCLK, PCLK1, PCLK2
    // AHB PR
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1;

    // APB1 PR
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV4;

    // APB2 PR
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV2;

    //5. Configure the MAIN PLL
    RCC->PLLCFGR = (PLL_M << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos) | (PLL_N << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos) | (PLL_Q << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_Pos) | (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE);

    //6. Enable the PLL and wait for it to become ready
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));

    //7. Set source
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL);
}
```

This is my UART2 config code:

```
void UART2_Config ( void )
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_USART2EN;  //clock UART
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;   //clock GPIOA
    GPIOA->MODER |= ( 2 << GPIO_MODER_MODER2_Pos ) | ( 2 << GPIO_MODER_MODER3_Pos ); //set PA2 and PA3 alternate function
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= ( 3 << GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED2_Pos ) | ( 3 << GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED3_Pos ); //clock GPIO pin at fastest speed
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= ( 7 << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL2_Pos ) | ( 7 << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL3_Pos ); //set PA2 and PA3 to alt func UART2

    USART2->CR1 = 0;
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;  //UART Enable
    //USART2->BRR = (0x16 << USART_BRR_DIV_Mantissa_Pos) | (0xc << USART_BRR_DIV_Fraction_Pos);  //Set Baud rate
    USART2->BRR = 4300;
    //USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE;  //Receiver enable
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE;  //Transmitter enable
    //Baud rate is off by a factor of 12ish
}
```

Finally, my main and while loop with the function for sending a character:

```
void UART2_SendChar ( uint8_t c )
{
    USART2->DR = c;
    while ( !(USART_SR_TC));
}

int main ( void )
{
    SysClockConfig();
    GPIO_Config();
    TIM10_Config();
    TIM12_Config();
    UART2_Config();
    //NVIC_SetPriority (TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn, 1);
    //NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn);

    NVIC_SetPriority (TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQn, 1);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQn);
    while ( 1 )
    {
        //GPIOD->BSRR |= (1<<12);
        //delay(2000000);
        //GPIOD->BSRR |= (1<<28);
        delay(4000000);
        UART2_SendChar('a');
    }
}
```

I can't find anything in the reference manual to explain this behavior. That tells me I am doing something wrong but I can't seem to track it down. On a final note, I had Putty set up to receive 9600 baud and played around with the BRR and setting it to a value of 4300 output the desired character. Plugging that value into the equation for baud in the reference manual gave me an insane system clock 660 MHz, again telling me I am missing something probably pretty obvious.

Comment: do not use magic numbers. use CMSIS bits definitions

Comment: Fair enough I was being lazy trying to hack this thing together. The original code has been fixed to use CMSIS declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502135/understanding-calculations-for-baud-rate-fractional-generator-stm32f4/572983#572983) recently, so let me copy that one:

**BRR** is a **Q12.4** format fixed point number, which needs one additional operation when `OVER8` mode is selected.

OP's question is about STM32F4, but if one inspects STM32F030 reference manual, he/she can find the same logic but represented by a different formula. IMO, that one (F030) is more clear and easier to understand.

To convert uint16_t (**Q16.0**) to **Q12.4**, you need to multiply it by 16.

Basically, for `OVER16` case, BRR is simply becomes `PeripheralClock / BaudRate`.

For `OVER8` case, you first need to calculate a temporary variable as `temp = 2 * PeripheralClock / BaudRate`. When writing it into **BRR**, you need to right-shift its lower 4 bits once.

See the example code:

```
void setBaudRate(uint32_t baud, bool over8)
{
    const uint32_t pClock = 42000000ull; // Hard-code or call a function to obtain it
    uint32_t usartDiv = (over8) ? (2 * pClock / baud) : (pClock / baud);

    uint32_t reg = USART1->BRR;
    reg &= ~0xffff; // Clear the lower 16 bits
    if (over8) {
        reg |= (usartDiv & 0xfff0) | ((usartDiv & 0xf) >> 1);
    }
    else { // over16
        reg |= usartDiv;
    }
    USART1->BRR = reg;
}
```

So, for your case, the correct value of **BRR** is **4375**.